# Google Places Api Error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, google-places-api

**Google Places Api**

I am implementing google place api in my project. I have implemented everything but google Api returns the following error:

> Current Place error: The operation couldn’t be completed. An internal
>   error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error
>   represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our
>   community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support).

It was working earlier but suddenly it stops. I found nothing in any other answer that could be helpful for me.

This my code to call the Api:

```
 GMSPlacesClient().currentPlace(callback: {
            (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in

            guard error == nil else {
                print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        })
```

Any Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: show some code.

Comment: Please check I have edited my question.

Comment: have you found what was the issue?

Comment: @pasevin no I didn't get any answer.

Comment: Hi can anyone suggest me what is wrong in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have given place_id instead of id.
This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

According to the GMSPlacesClient reference (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client) you should be accessing the shared instance of the client, so in Swift 3 your code above should be

```
GMSPlacesClient.shared().currentPlace(callback: {
        (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    })
```